# Bolinha vermelha em "Publicações de baixa qualidade"

Tags: suporte

O que seria essa bolinha no menu de análise ?

[image: Menu]

Comment: *Quando o titulo da pergunta duplicada é melhor que da mais antiga* - +1 pelo título "descritivo", mesmo que dup, gosto muito de titulos que possam evidenciar melhor o problema, talvez depois eu edite a outra pergunta :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significa que existe um número considerável (10, salvo erro) de items na fila de análise.

Comment: Entendi. Realmente tinham bastantes, mas depois que terminei todas, continua a bolinha vermelha. Será que ele considera a revisão dos outros também ?

Comment: @RBZ não me parece, eu acabei de fazer as revisões nessa fila (também tinha a bolinha vermelha) e depois de terminadas as revisões, a bolinha desapareceu. Tente fazer *refresh* da página?

Comment: Tentei de tudo, até abrir no modo privado e não saiu. Agora saiu, sem refresh sem nada ! rs

Comment: Estranhamente, voltou a bolinha, sem revisões na fila !